# Is it possible to generate a message when precision upgrade occur?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, precision-and-accuracy, message-coding

I use *Mathematica* mostly for numerical simulation, so most of the time double precision (or machine precision) is enough for me. *Mathematica* has this nice feature of automatically upgrade to arbitrary precision, but sometimes it costs problems for me.

For instance here is a compiled function that calculate a modulus of a vector

```
mymod = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, x.x]
```

Now a vector has a Gaussian distribution

```
ListPlot[Array[Exp[-(#)^2./10.] &, 500, {-100., 100.}]]
```

[image]

and we want to calculate its modulus

```
mymod[Array[Exp[-(#)^2./10.]&,500,{-100.,100.}]]
(* 9.8885 *)
```

we get the right answer but with a warning saying that the argument type is incorrect:

> Argument
>   {5.075958897549*10^-435,1.513073408369*10^-431,4.367658965168*10^-428,<<45>>,5.42928*10^-284,3.46203*10^-281,<<450>>} at position 1 should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers.

That's because `Exp` has upgraded the machine precision number we use to arbitrary precision. And thus the uncompiled function is invoked.

Consider the situation where we use extensively the numerical functions in a fairly large package, this automatic upgrading of precision may occur at multiple places. Although the final answer may probably be correct, invoking the uncompiled functions may greatly degrade the performance.

One solution point out by Daniel Lichtblau [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7586910/1363677) is to turn off the tracking of the underflow by setting `"CatchMachineUnderflow"->False` to every function that uses arbitrary precision. But first we need to find those functions.

So my question are:

1. Is it possible to tell *Mathematica* to generate a message when the upgrading to an arbitrary precision occurs? Just like we can have a message if the unpacking of an array occurs.
2. This precision problem seems to be quite common for people dealing with numerical calculation in *Mathematica*. What do you think are good ways to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 7):

> ... turn off the tracking of the underflow by setting
>   "CatchMachineUnderflow"->False to every function that uses arbitrary
>   precision. But first we need to find those functions.

This will take effect system-wide:

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False];
```

Then the following will underflow to a machine zero, instead of turning into a tiny bigreal:

```
    Exp[-800.]    

    (* 0. *)
```

This may become the default (and only) behavior in a future version.

Comment: Do you know (or could you help me find out) if [using Shared passing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164566/12) is a reasonable way to return multiple results from a LibraryLink function?  There are so many things that can go wrong that I am not confident about using this method. Maybe there is a caveat I have not thought of.  For example, running `Share[]` will share the internal storage of some identical expressions. Can it share the storage of packed arrays too?  If yes, that could make things go wrong in yet another way ...

Comment: With Version 11.3, your command results in the error message,

Comment: Yes, not trapping machine underflow is the default (and only) behavior in 11.3 and later. Since there is no longer a choice, this system option has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

In your example it may be acceptable to merely `Clip` the input to `mymod`:

```
mymod[
 Clip[
  Array[Exp[-(#)^2./10.] &, 500, {-100., 100.}],
  {$MinMachineNumber, $MaxMachineNumber}
 ]
]
```

> ```
> 9.8885
> ```

In a form to reapply, along with Message generation:

```
catch::foo = "argument clipped";

catch[fn_][args__] := 
  With[{clipped = Clip[{args}, {$MinMachineNumber, $MaxMachineNumber}]},
    If[{args} =!= clipped, Message[catch::foo]];
    fn @@ clipped
  ]
```

Now:

```
catch[mymod] @ Array[Exp[-(#)^2./10.] &, 500, {-100., 100.}]
```

> During evaluation of In[]:= catch::foo: argument clipped
>
> ```
> 9.8885
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but that requires to put that snippet of code to all the functions in a package, which seems a little bit tedious. I guess I'm trying to asking a event kind like message. For instance, giving some black box function, is it possible to catch that?

Comment: For example, giving this function `f[n_] := Module[{mymod},
  mymod = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, x.x];
  mymod[Array[Exp[-(#)^2./10.] &, n, {-100., 100.}]]
  ]` is it possible to catch the even like `catch[f[500]]`?

Comment: @xslittlegrass I'll think about what you're trying to accomplish and update my answer if I come up with anything I consider actually serviceable.