# Catching MachineUnderflow in Version 11.3

Tags: system, system-variables, version-11.3

Ilian's [answer to question 72229](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163131/1063), involves

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]
```

Evidently, this worked in earlier versions of Mathematica, but in version "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)", it does not, returning

> SetSystemOptions::sysname: CatchMachineUnderflow is not a known SystemOption.

Does an alternative exist in the new version of Mathematica?

Comment: Does `SetSystemOptions["CheckMachineUnderflow" -> False]` work for you?

Comment: No, this is a different option that controls whether a machine underflow warning is issued in some circumstances. But there is no way to automatically switch to arbitrary precision as in earlier versions.

Comment: @ilian Thanks for the info. I wonder what the reason behind this design decision was...

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for telling me =D

Comment: @bbgodfrey Alternative in what sense? This command is simply not needed in 11.3 and later because what it accomplishes is now the default (and only) behavior, so you can think of "CatchMachineUnderflow" as being permanently set to False. There are also some new warning messages that can be easily turned off.

Comment: @ilian  Point well taken.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just want to save this information from comments. [@ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) mentioned [in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174474/catching-machineunderflow-in-version-11-3#comment458076_174474):

> This command is simply not needed in 11.3 and later because what it accomplishes is now the default (and only) behavior, so you can think of `CatchMachineUnderflow` as being permanently set to `False`. There are also some new warning messages that can be easily turned off.

Answer (score 0):

In version 12.0, we should set `SetSystemOptions["CheckMachineUnderflow"->False]`. In this way, we can turn off the prompt message.

Comment: As mentioned by ilian [in the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174474/catching-machineunderflow-in-version-11-3#comment458076_174474), this option won't help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt. I will check the comments carefully again.