# MathLink: How do I send a bigint?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, librarylink

Suppose I have a big integer from some library such as GMP. I need to return this from a LibraryLink function. What is the most efficient way to do it?

The simplest way is to convert it to a string `stringRepr` then use MathLink to send `ToExpression[stringRepr]`. Is there a more direct way, using the binary representation? Is there a way that avoids the need to send an explicit `ToExpression`?

Comment: How are bigints sent the other way?

Comment: @Roman That's a reasonable thought, but it seems that different functions return the result in different formats. However, if `MLGetData` returns it in a textual form, that would hint that `MLPutData` must send it in the same form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following sequence of calls appears to work:

```c
const char *stringRepr = "123456";

MLPutNext(link, MLTKINT); /* put an integer */
MLPutSize(link, strlen(stringRepr));
MLPutData(link, stringRepr, strlen(stringRepr));
```

It was not originally clear to me that `MLPutData` must send a string representation of the integer. This is mentioned [in the J/Link documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/ref/java/com/wolfram/jlink/MathLink.html#putData-byte:A-), but I was unable to find it in the documentation of the C MathLink API.

It is still not clear to me why an `MLPutSize` is necessary if we need to specify the size in `MLPutData` as well. Perhaps this is because the data can be sent in multiple chunks with multiple `MLPutData` calls?

---

Finally, a question is if this is indeed the most efficient way. It seems like a clean way because it avoids `ToExpression`. But simply returning a string with LibraryLink (not through MathLink), then applying `ToExpression` afterwards seems to be about 2x faster than sending the textual representation of a large integer through MathLink.

```
Do[returnBigintML[], {1000}] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0073, Null} *)

Do[ToExpression[returnStringLL[]]], {1000}] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0037, Null} *)
```

Related:

- [MathLink (WSTP) vs LibraryLink performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91887/12)

---

**Update** based on the comment of @ihojnicki. This also works:

```
MLPutType(link, MLTKINT);
MLPutString(link, stringRepr);
```

Comment: It is easier to use `MLPutType()` followed by `MLPutString()` and friends.

Comment: @ihojnicki Thank you, this works. I am struggling with MathLink because I am missing the conceptual foundations. It would be useful to explain these in the documentation. In this case, I assumed that `MLPutString` can only put the `String` datatype. It seems this is not true. It can put a string representation of anything. The actual type is indicated with `MLPutType`.

Comment: @ihojnicki But now I do not understand what the difference is between `MLPutType` and `MLPutNext`. It's also not clear what are the valid sequences of calls in cases when multiple functions need to be used together.

Comment: I believe `MLPutNext` is the precursor to `MLPutType`, but I'd have to glance through the code.  That is probably not going to happen today though.

Comment: @ihojnicki In this context, they both _appear_ to work. If you do figure out the difference, here's the question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199714/12

Comment: `FromDigits` should be faster than `ToExpression`.