# MathLink: What is the difference between MLPutNext and MLPutType?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

What is the difference between `MLPutNext` and `MLPutType` (also called [WSPutNext](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/c/WSPutNext.html) and [WSPutType](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/c/WSPutType.html))?

Their documentation is virtually identical (and lacking for both).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`XXPutNext` is `XXPutType`.  I'm pretty certain `XXPutNext` exists only for backwards compatibility reasons.