# Should I worry about concurrent access to LibraryLinked code?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, librarylink, c++, return-value

According to [these answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31545/16127), when several heterogeneous results (say `{MTensor, mint, double}`) are needed to be returned from a LibraryLink `computation()`, the way to go is to store the results in some global library state, and then retrieve every field `MTensor`, `mint`, `double` with a new dedicated function like `retrieve_array_from_computation()`, `retrieve_int_from_computation()` and `retrieve_real_from_computation()`.

Does this imply that some `{MTensor, mint, double}` struct must be kept in some global state within the library?
If yes, should I worry about possible concurrent access, *e.g.* if the Mathematica user is calling into `computation()` from a `ParallelTable` or so?

In this case I should store not only a `{MTensor, mint, double}` in the global state, but a whole random-access collection of such objects protected by a mutex. And `computation()` should return some index into the collection, that the caller in a thread must use in order not to retrieve the results computed in another thread.

While I'm okay with doing all this, I'm not confident it's truly needed because I'm not sure what's the memory model for parallelism with `LibraryLink`. Will library global space be actually shared among threads, or will each kernel run its own independent version of the loaded library?

Comment: Mathematica does parallelization by running multiple, separate processes that do not share memory. Mathematica does not support shared-memory parallelization.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh, so you mean that I do not need be worried about synchronizing access to the global mutable state? Every parallel worker will have its own copy of my lib singleton(s) :) That's good news. Thanks!

Comment: For returning multiple results, do take a look at this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/247056/12

Comment: @Szabolcs Wow, that sounds awesome, thank you :D I'm curious (and a bit afraid) why DataStores are not documented.. why is that? Does this imply that they have no stability guarantee ?

Comment: @iago-lito DataStore is not documented because it's API has been added to LibraryLink relatively recently and more effort at Wolfram is now directed towards finishing the new compiler which is supposed to completely alleviate the need to use LibraryLink. As for the no stability guarantee - that is correct.

Comment: @rafalc Okay, thanks.. well, let's go for DataStore and cross my fingers then ;)